# Mapping DataFrame values to another DataFrame based on index 'month' and column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have two DataFrames. df_A is indexed with end of month values and df_B is indexed daily, but has an end of month column for reference. The [column] for which values that I'm looking to extract need to be "looked-up" via df_B['ref'] and matched based upon ['month'] in each df.

DataFrame: df_A

| month | colA | colB | colC | colD | colE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000-01-31 | val | val | val | val | val |
| 2000-02-29 | val | val | val | val | val |
| 2000-03-31 | val | val | val | val | val |

DataFrame df_B

| date | month | ref | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000-01-01 | 2000-01-31 | colA | val from df_A |
| 2000-01-02 | 2000-01-31 | colD | val from df_A |
| 2000-01-03 | 2000-01-31 | colB | val from df_A |
| 2000-01-04 | 2000-01-31 | colC | val from df_A |

What's the Pythonic way of achieving df_B['result']? Is there a list comprehension or lambdas solution that could do this without resorting to a massive, compute-intensive for/if/loop.

P.S. I asking because I'm currently already into a couple nested for-loops as the overarching real life problem is a bit more complicated. Stacking additional loops makes my brain hurt...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `df_A` data needs to be converted from a wide format to a long format, you can do that effectively here with `pd.melt`

The melted data looks something like this:

```
         month    ref   value
0   2000-01-31  colA    val
1   2000-02-29  colA    val
2   2000-03-31  colA    val
3   2000-01-31  colB    val
```

Where you can see that the column names are melted into a single column, which then makes it easy to join with your other dataframe.

```
df_B.merge(df_A.melt(id_vars='month', var_name='ref'), on=['month','ref'] )
```

Output

```
         date       month   ref         result value
0  2000-01-01  2000-01-31  colA  val from df_A   val
1  2000-01-02  2000-01-31  colD  val from df_A   val
2  2000-01-03  2000-01-31  colB  val from df_A   val
3  2000-01-04  2000-01-31  colC  val from df_A   val
```

Comment: Thank you. pd.melt and merge was absolutely the right way to go here. Why didn't I think of pd.melt!!! ;)  I would note for anyone that eventually finds this thread that there's a few additional things to keep in mind. a) you can't pass in df.index for id_vars, only the name reference of a column in the melt; otherwise you'll get a KeyError. b) it's nice to keep the original index for df_B in this example, which was achieved by adding .set_index(df_B.index) at the end of the merge command.